# Finding set images given function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My given function is $f(x)= x^2 + 1$.

a) $f( [-1,0] \cup [2,4])$ and I got for my answer $[1,17]$

b) $f^{-1}([5,10])$ and I got $[-3,-2] \cup [2,3]$

I am not sure if my answers are correct. This is for set images. I am using the definition of functions and restrictions.

Comment: What function is $F$?

Comment: I think it's clear that $f$ and $F$ are the same.

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento yes they are the same

Comment: @Fimpellizieri someone made an edit and I guess they forgot to keep them the same

Comment: Use \cup and \cap for union and intersection.

Comment: @user254665 I am not too sure how to do this someone made edits to my question

Comment: You can edit your own Q, I think. regardless of your " reputation number". Click on "edit" below your Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1). For $0\leq a\leq b$:

(i). Since $f(-x)=f(x)$ for every $x,$ we have $f([-b,-a])=f([a,b]).$

$$\text {(ii): }\; f(x)\in [f(a),f(b)]\iff a^2+1\leq x^2+1\iff a^2\leq c^2\leq b^2\iff$$ $$\iff a\leq |x|\leq b\iff  x\in [-b,-a]\cup [a,b].$$ $$\text {Therefore }\; f([a,b])\;\cup \;f( [-b,-a])\subset [f(a),f(b)].$$

(iii): If $y\in [f(a),f(b)]$ then $y\geq f(a)\geq 0$ so $\sqrt {y-1}$ exists  and $ \sqrt {y-1}\in [a,b]$ with $f(\sqrt {y-1})=y.$ $$ \text {Therefore }\;  [f(a),f(b)]\subset f([a,b])= f([-b,-a])\; \cup \; [f(a),f(b)].$$ (The equality is by (i).)

(iv). From (ii) and (iii) we have $$f([-b,-a]\cup [a,b])=[f(a),f(b)].$$

(2). For $1\leq a'\leq b',$ let $a=\sqrt {a'-1}$ and $b=\sqrt {b'-1}.$ We have $0\leq a\leq b.$

(i).   By (1)(iv), we have $f([-b,-a]\cup [a,b]=[f(a),f(b)]=[a',b'].$ $$\text {Therefore }\;  f^{-1}([a',b'])\supset [-b,-a]\cup [a,b].$$

(ii). If $|x|>b$ or $|x|<a$ then $f(x)>f(b)=b'$ or $f(x)<f(a)=a'.$ $$\text {Therefore }\;  f^{-1}([a',b'])\subset [-b,-a]\cup [a,b].$$

(iii). From (i) and (ii), therefore $$f^{-1}([a',b'])=[-b,-a]\cup [a,b]=[-\sqrt {b'-1} , -\sqrt {a'-1}]\cup [\sqrt {a'-1},\sqrt {b'-1}].$$

(3). By (1)(iv) we have $f([-1,0]\cup [2,4])=f([-1,0])\cup f([2,4])=f([0,1])\cup f([2,4])=[f(0),f(1)]\cup [f(2),f(4)]=$ $$=[1,2]\cup [5,17].$$  Note that,for example, $f(x)=3\iff |x|=\sqrt 2 ,$ and $\sqrt 2\not \in [-1,0]\cup [2,4].$

By (2)(iii) we have  $f^{-1}([5,10])=[-\sqrt {10-1},-\sqrt {5-1}]\cup [\sqrt {5-1},\sqrt {10-1}]= [-3,-2]\cup [2,3].$

This may seem to be methodological over-kill. But is an excellent exercise to wite out a proof in detail, in complete sentences, stating how each step is obtained, and stating whether each logical connector is "implies" or "iff" or "is implied by".